# how to let .visible = false; stay false in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I have made an code so if you click on an object the object dissapears and for that I used this code:

```
flap1.visible = false;
```

but the object needs to stay false during the whole animation

Comment: What could be setting it true?

Comment: @Panzercrisis if I play my animation again it becomes true again

Comment: Could you show us the code around where you're making it play again please?

Answer (score 1):

Flash timelines are kind of like a static state machine; moving from frame-to-frame will run all of the document code at that frame (every time). [It also resets the value of the content to the state it was in during design time](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/orderofoperations/) (so, frame = design + code). Because of the headaches this model can cause, I highly recommend you do all of your design & code in a single frame. In short, *don't use timelines*.

If you're not ready to make the shift, and want to make sure it stays hidden, you'll need to  set the visibility of `flap1` at each frame. This might look something like this:

```
function toggleBtnListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (flap1.visible) {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = false;
    } else {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = true;
    }
}

flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility;
```

---

### Comment Response

The code you pasted has two issues:

- You moved the `flap1.visible` setting to the inside of the `Click` listener.  You want it outside of the listener so that it gets called on every frame
- You have your import statements inside the listener.  Always place these at the top of your code before you use the classes.

**Revised code:**

```
import gs.*;
import gs.easing.*;
TweenMax.to(movieclip1, 2, {scaleX:4, scaleY:4, ease:Elastic.easeOut});

function move_to_top(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (flap1.visible) {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = false;
    } else {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = true;
    }
    animateClip()
} 

flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility;
animateClip()

function animateClip():void {
    if (flap1.visible == false) {
        this.setChildIndex(movieclip1, this.numChildren - 1);
        flap1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, move_to_top);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my code I added your code but it still doen't work, it is called move_to_top because it has to flap1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, move_to_top); // Add the button click

function move_to_top(e:MouseEvent):void {
if (flap1.visible) {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = false;
    } else {
        flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility = true;
    }

flap1.visible = this.flap1Visibility;

this.setChildIndex(movieclip1, this.numChildren - 1);




    

import gs.*; 
import gs.easing.*;

TweenMax.to(movieclip1, 2, {scaleX:4, scaleY:4, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
}

Comment: no it must be like this flap1 is an object if i click on flap1 movieclip1 has to come to the top and easeout and flap1 has to become false and stay false when I use your way it starts already easing out whitout me clicking on flap1

Comment: Updated code accordingly.  That said, this is a really simple logic problem.  If you want something to happen in a particular order, it's just a matter of following the same logic the environment will take when reading your code.  Ask yourself, "what steps would I take to do this?", and write your code to follow your steps/logic.  If this resolves your issue, please don't forget to accept.

Comment: @Atrice this isnot what I asked you I only want that if I click flap1 that flap1 becomes false not that hard I thought but what I get is that flap1 is already false